# Title bar color change in mfc SDI application

Tags: mfc

I am able to change the dialog title bar color with the following:-

```
void CactiveSampleDlg::OnNcPaint()
{
    CDC* pDC = GetWindowDC();
    CRect CapRct;
    GetWindowRect(&CapRct);

    long myFillColour = RGB(200, 0, 0);
    long myTextColour = RGB(0, 0, 0);
    int x1 = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXDLGFRAME);
    int y1 = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYDLGFRAME);
    int x2 = CapRct.Width() - GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXDLGFRAME);
    int y2 = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYICON) - GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYDLGFRAME) - GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYBORDER);

    CapRct.left = x1;
    CapRct.top = y1;
    CapRct.right = x2;
    CapRct.bottom = y2;
    pDC->FillSolidRect(&CapRct, myFillColour);

    CFont* pCurFont = GetFont();
    LOGFONT lf;
    pCurFont->GetLogFont (&lf);
    lf.lfItalic = TRUE;
    lf.lfWeight = FW_NORMAL;
    lf.lfWidth  = 12;
    lf.lfHeight = 18;
    strcpy(reinterpret_cast<char*>(lf.lfFaceName) ,"Veranda");

    CFont capfont ;
    capfont.CreateFontIndirect (&lf);
    pCurFont = pDC->SelectObject (&capfont);
    pDC->SetBkMode (TRANSPARENT);
    pDC->SetTextColor (GetSysColor(COLOR_CAPTIONTEXT));
    pDC->DrawText (_T("<Dialog Text>"), &CapRct, DT_CENTER | DT_VCENTER);
}
```

But when I apply the same in SDI application, it is giving assertion error pCurFont->GetLogFont (&lf);
Can anybody guide me , how to resolve the same or If there is better medium to do so. I would like to change the color of title bar including setting the font for the caption of title bar and close button should be available as well

Comment: The assertion dialog tells you what's wrong. Once you fixed that issue, you can tackle the others. Like destroying a font, while it's still selected into a device context. Or trying to create a font with a typeface that doesn't exist (it's called `"Verdana"`, not `"Veranda"`). Don't expect to get anywhere with a demonstrated lack of diligence.

Comment: I found that CFont* pCurFont = GetFont(); function return null, and found that it is because of System font used,so how I can change the font of the titleBar in sdi application? is it possible with some minor change in the code snippet, I shared earlier or not?

Comment: Dereferencing a NULL pointer doesn't trigger a debug assertion. Your problem description is inconclusive. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: I had shared the complete function in my earlier post, What is more expected ?

As per my understanding GetFont() is returning null, which is the route cause of the problem, because when I used the same function in dialog based application(OnNCPaint()), it working fine.

Comment: You should not rely on GetFont() as this is no standard feature, but only supported by some MFC windows classes. Better create your font in another way.

Comment: You are asking about an SDI application, but posted code that suggests that you're implementing a dialog-based application. That's not a [mcve]. @nic: `GetFont()` isn't specific to MFC. It just sends a [WM_GETFONT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/wm-getfont) message, so this is indeed a standard feature.

Comment: @IInspectable Ok, you're right, it's not MFC specific. But anyway it's supported only by some window classes, others just ignore SetFont and return NULL for GetFont.

Comment: @nic: That's not correct either. From [WM_SETFONT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/wm-setfont): *"The `WM_SETFONT` message applies to all controls, not just those in dialog boxes."* `WM_GETFONT` returns `NULL`, if the control uses the system font. The implication that the control were to not support `WM_SETFONT` is incorrect. It does, it's just that no one has sent a `WM_SETFONT` message with a custom font.

Comment: @IInspectable I made some weird experiences on this, but it's too long ago to insist on details. One thing I can still read from my source code: Controls use their parent dialog's font by default, not the system font.